# how to create json image and text list view? Please explain the correct format for onitemclicklistener with example?

Tags: java, android, xml, json

I am tring to onitemclicklistener is working but content is not  displayed.
Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    private static final String TAG_details = "details";

    ListView mListView; String tv_country_details; 

    @Override 

    public void onCreate(Bundle  savedInstanceState) 
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // URL to the JSON data
    String strUrl = "http://http://192.168.0.200/android/count.php";

    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    // Starting the download process
    downloadTask.execute(strUrl);

    // Getting a reference to ListView of activity_main
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);


      }

    /** A method to download json data from url */ 

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{   {
    String data = "";

    InputStream iStream = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";

        while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }
    finally
    {
        iStream.close();
    }

    return data; 
    } 
      } 
    /** AsyncTask to download json data */ 

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    String data = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread
        ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();

        // Start parsing xml data
        listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);

    } 
  }   

    /** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */ 

    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>implements OnItemClickListener
    { 
        JSONObject jObject;

       // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread

       @Override

      protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
            CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();
            countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            String visibility = jObject.getString("visibility");
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
        }

        // Instantiating json parser class
        CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();

        // A list object to store the parsed countries list
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;

        try{
            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","details"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.iv_flag,R.id.tv_country_details};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items

      // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item

       SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override           

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
    {
        String tv_country_details = getIntent().getStringExtra("details");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,         SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("TAG_details", tv_country_details);
                startActivity(intent);;  }

    });             

    return adapter;


    }

    /** Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed */

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

        // Setting adapter for the listview
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
            String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
            ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

            HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put("flag_path",imgUrl);
            hm.put("position", i);

            // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview
            imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
        }
    }

        @Override       
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {           
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }

     }   

    /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */ 

    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void,  HashMap<String, Object>>{

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

        InputStream iStream=null;
        String im,gUrl;
        gUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
        int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(gUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            // Getting Caching directory
            File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

            // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
            File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");

            // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
            FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

            // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

            // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

            // Flush the FileOutputStream
            fOutStream.flush();

           //Close the FileOutputStream
           fOutStream.close();

            // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // Storing the path to the temporary image file
            hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());

            // Storing the position of the image in the listview
            hmBitmap.put("position",position);

            // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
            return hmBitmap;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
        // Getting the path to the downloaded image
        String path = (String) result.get("flag");

        // Getting the position of the downloaded image
        int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

        // Getting adapter of the listview
        SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) mListView.getAdapter();

        // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);

        // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
        hm.put("flag",path);

        // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

         }
```

## Json Parser Code ##

```
public class CountryJSONParser {   
// Receives a JSONObject and returns a list 
public List<HashMap<String,Object>>   parse(JSONObject jObject) {

JSONArray jCountries = null;

try {
    // Retrieves all the elements in the 'countries' array
    jCountries = jObject.getJSONArray("countries");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Invoking getCountries with the array of json object
// where each json object represent a country
return getCountries(jCountries); 
}   
private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getCountries(JSONArray jCountries) {

 int countryCount = jCountries.length();

   List<HashMap<String, Object>> countryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

         HashMap<String, Object> country = null;

// Taking each country, parses and adds to list object
for(int i=0; i<countryCount;i++){
    try {
        // Call getCountry with country JSON object to parse the country
        country = getCountry((JSONObject)jCountries.get(i));
        countryList.add(country);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

return countryList; 
}   
// Parsing the Country JSON object private HashMap<String, Object> getCountry(JSONObject  jCountry){

HashMap<String, Object> country = new HashMap<String, Object>();

String flag="";
String currencyName = "";

try {

    flag = jCountry.getString("flag");
    currencyName = jCountry.getJSONObject("currency").getString("currencyname");

    String details = currencyName ;


    country.put("flag", R.drawable.blank);
    country.put("flag_path", flag);
    country.put("details", details);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return country; }

public static Object optJSONObject(int arg2) {      
// TODO Auto-generated method stub          
return null;    
}                        


public static boolean isNull(int arg2) {        

   // TODO Auto-generated method stub       
  return false;     
 } 
   }
```

## SingleMenuitemActivity code  ##

- List item

  public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

  ```
  // JSON node keys
      String tv_country_details;          
        @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

          Intent i = getIntent();
          // Get the result of rank
          tv_country_details = i.getStringExtra("tv_country_details");

          // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
          TextView txttv_country_details = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_country_details);
  ```

  // Set results to the TextViews
              txttv_country_details.setText(tv_country_details);

  ```
      }
  ```

  }

Comment: You would have to change your RequestURI to run the app. Change the `192.168.0.200` to `10.0.2.2`

Comment: Hi sir, i was use 10.0.2.2 url but not working listview what do?

Comment: Did u get any error/exception while using `10.0.2.2` ? Did u try debugging your application ?

Comment: Hi sir,This error will be occur                                   04-04 05:10:42.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1096): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 05:10:42.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: How to fix this problem

Comment: Can you somewhat edit your question to add your full stack-trace. Its hard to figure out with just a single line. Get your stack-trace from the logcat

Comment: I was finished proper code reedit. So please verify and tell me how to fix this sir.